# lemmatize very long texts in python

Tags: python, performance

i really need to optimize this piece of code for my master thesis. it take up to 20 seconds to lemmatize documents with >6000 words. the problem is that i have to lemmatize more than 200.000 documents with an avarage of 10.000 words each.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk 
import gensim
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from collections import defaultdict


lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):
    options = defaultdict(lambda: "", {'J': wordnet.ADJ, 'V': wordnet.VERB, 'N': wordnet.NOUN, "R": wordnet.ADV})
    return options[treebank_tag[0]]

def preprocess(text):
    result=[]
    
    tokens = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text)

    text_pos = list(zip(tokens,[get_wordnet_pos(nltk.pos_tag(tokens)[i][1]) for i in range(len(nltk.pos_tag(tokens)))]))

    text_pos_cleaned = [text_pos[i] for i,n in enumerate(text_pos) if text_pos[i][1] != '']

    lemmatized = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(text_pos_cleaned[i][0], text_pos_cleaned[i][1]) for i in range(0,len(text_pos_cleaned))]

    [result.append(token) for token in lemmatized if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and len(token) > 3]
    
    return result

dummy_text= "strangeWordWithNoMeaning  and i am a good guys with very important values he is a good student, i am reading books and making cake rectangles to be better than any other students, he has very interesting abilities, oqf and i am so proud"
preprocess(dummy_text)
```

thank you in advance all.

Comment: Have you analyzed the performance of the WordNetLemmatizer? The problem with helping you optimize this code is that it is depending on a lot of external code. If there is internet communication going on during the execution of the program that can be part of the problem.

Comment: thank you, i think that in order to achieve better performances i need to work on that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been playing with your code a bit, and I have two key recommendations for you.

##### Bring the code back from quadratic time to linear time

The most important gain requires fixing this line:

```
text_pos = list(zip(tokens,[get_wordnet_pos(nltk.pos_tag(tokens)[i][1]) for i in range(len(nltk.pos_tag(tokens)))]))
```

Notice how you're calling `nltk.pos_tag(tokens)` on the whole set of tokens again for each token you're processing. This way, you've made the computational cost quadratic in the number of tokens in a document instead of just linear. You can bring computational time back to linear by calculating it just once for the document:

```
pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
text_pos = list(zip(tokens, [get_wordnet_pos(tag[1]) for tag in pos_tags]))
```

##### The `nltk` initializations are expensive

I also noticed that a lot of time is just spent in the initialization of the data structures.

- The imports alone take 3-4 seconds on my machine, and
- the line

  ```
  options = defaultdict(lambda: "", {'J': wordnet.ADJ, 'V': wordnet.VERB, 'N': wordnet.NOUN, "R": wordnet.ADV})
  ```

  takes 2 seconds by itself!

After that, the rest of the script is quite fast (with my fix above), taking just a fraction of a second on my machine.

While the rest of your code could certainly be optimized further, you will get a worthwhile additional gain by looping over all your files inside your Python program rather than by calling your program in the shell loop for each document.

##### Minor thing: iterate over items, not indices

In Python, we don't usually iterate over indices, but rather directly over the elements of any iterable structure.

For example:

```
text_pos_cleaned = [text_pos[i] for i,n in enumerate(text_pos) if text_pos[i][1] != '']
```

can be written more efficiently as:

```
text_pos_cleaned = [item for item in text_pos if item[1]]
```

The code is shorter and easier to read (imho) but also faster, because iteration already yields one item at a time for you, you don't have to find the item at each position while you loop.

Comment: i don't know how to express my gratitude. With just some simple changes the code went from taking up to 20 seconds per 5000 words to 0.1s. Really appreciate <3

Comment: You're most welcome, I'm glad I could help. Accepting my answer was indeed the normal way to express your gratitude on this site, thanks for doing so.